# CasperJS not loading javascripts?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
viewportSize: {
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
},
verbose: true,
logLevel: 'debug'
});

var utils = require('utils');
casper.options.onResourceRequested = function(C, requestData, request) {
    utils.dump(requestData.headers);
};
var url = casper.cli.get('url');
var filename = casper.cli.get('filename');
var headers = casper.cli.get('storefront');

if (headers != null) {
    casper.userAgent('iTunes/12.4.3 (Windows; Microsoft Windows 10.0 x64 Business Edition (Build 9200); x64) AppleWebKit/7601.6016.1000.7');
}

casper.start().then(function() {
    casper.page.customHeaders = {
        'X-Apple-Store-Front': headers,
        'X-Apple-Tz': '3600'
    };
    casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
       this.wait(2000, function() {
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.write('asd.html', this.getHTML(), 'wb');
        this.capture(filename);
    });
});
});
casper.run();
```

`casperjs screenshot.js --storefront="143441-1,12 ab:SwTTXLh0" --url="https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?cc=us&id=37" --filename=tv.jpg`

When attempting to dump this page, it's not giving me the full javascript carousel or anything. I honestly have no idea what's causing the failure to load and was wondering if anyone has had any other experiences with this?

The PhantonJS version is 2.1.1. The CasperJS version is 1.1.1.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Updated the post. 

`Error: ITSExceptionHandler: ITSExceptionHandler:{message:"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: iTunes", url:"https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/CBCB/dt-storefront-base.js", lineNumber:"1023"}`
`Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: iTunes`

casperjs version is 1.1.1

Comment: PhantomJS is 2.1.1 also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. There are a few things to check in this [PhantomJS ticket](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11529):

- Try outputting the html that Casper interprets using `this.debugHTML()` to see if the script you want to load is in the actual html (might be omitted because of weird/old userAgent)
- Webkit version you're using
- Try looking at the network traffic through `onResourceRequested` and `onResourceReceived` to see if the script is actually requested and received.

Sadly all of these looked ok in my case but the page is still blank. Hope it might help someone else. Let me know if you have other tips on what to check.